# ValueError : while building Doc out of a story within Reportlab python

Tags: python, pdf, build, reportlab

I am currently working with reportlab to create an automated report after a machine learning process. Well It does create a perfect report on windows. But when I try to put my work on a distant server, everything works perfectly til it comes to the "doc.build(Story)" thing

`File "train_prediction.py", line 551, in create_pdfdoc pdf_doc.build(story) 
File "/home/adservio/periosystem/perio-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 1038, in build self.handle_flowable(flowables) 
File "/home/adservio/periosystem/perio-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 892, in handle_flowable if frame.add(f, canv, trySplit=self.allowSplitting): 
File "/home/adservio/periosystem/perio-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/frames.py", line 167, in _add w, h = flowable.wrap(aW, h) 
File "/home/adservio/periosystem/perio-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 495, in wrap return self.drawWidth, self.drawHeight 
File "/home/adservio/periosystem/perio-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 489, in getattr self._setup_inner() 
File "/home/adservio/periosystem/perio-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 457, in _setup_inner self.drawWidth = width or self.imageWidth ValueError: The truth va
lue of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

```
def create_pdfdoc(pdfdoc, story):
"""
Creates PDF doc from story.
"""
pdf_doc = BaseDocTemplate(pdfdoc, pagesize = PAGE_SIZE,
    leftMargin = MARGIN_SIZE, rightMargin = MARGIN_SIZE,
    topMargin = MARGIN_SIZE, bottomMargin = MARGIN_SIZE)
main_frame = Frame(MARGIN_SIZE, MARGIN_SIZE,
    PAGE_SIZE[0] - 2 * MARGIN_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE[1] - 2 * MARGIN_SIZE,
    leftPadding = 0, rightPadding = 0, bottomPadding = 0,
    topPadding = 0, id = 'main_frame')
main_template = PageTemplate(id = 'main_template', frames = [main_frame])
pdf_doc.addPageTemplates([main_template])

pdf_doc.build(story)
```

Comment: I am currently working with reportlab to create an automated report after a machine learning process. Well It does create a perfect report on windows. But when I try to put my work on a distant server, everything works perfectly til it comes to the "doc.build(Story)" thing

Comment: Do you have the code that the error is associated with?

Comment: yes I will add it below ! the Story in the doc.build(Story) is an array and I checked the content on windows and on server, it is obviously the same... I think the error isn't due to the code ...

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code

Comment: Done, I hope it could be helpful